# When is $a^2 \equiv b^2 \pmod n \implies a\equiv b \pmod n$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic

I know that: $$a\equiv b \pmod n \implies a^2 \equiv b^2 \pmod n $$ But this is not an equivalence relation so we cannot say that if:
$$a^2 \equiv b^2 \pmod n \implies a\equiv b \pmod n $$

But are there some restrictions that makes this proposition true?

Comment: E.g. $n$ prime and $n \nmid a+b$.

Comment: For prime $n$ you get $a^2\equiv b^2\implies a\equiv \pm b$ (all $\pmod n$). That's all you have in any field...what more would you hope for?

Comment: it works only for primes $n$ ? @lulu

Comment: Well, try some examples.  For $n=15$, the congruence $a^2\equiv 1 \pmod {15}$ has four solutions, namely $\{1, 4, 11, 14\}\pmod {15}$.  Using the Chinese Remainder Theorem, you can see that there are always exactly $4$ solutions to $a^2\equiv 1 \pmod {pq}$ for distinct odd primes $p,q$.

Comment: Not just primes.  Is true for $n=6$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two things:

If $(-a)^2 = a^2$ so $(-a)^2 \equiv a^2 \pmod n$ so unless $a\equiv -a \pmod n$ is always true this can't ever be true.

And if $n$ isn't prime and $n = jk$ then $a^2 \equiv b^2 \mod n$ will imply $a^2 -b^2=(a+b)(a-b)\equiv 0 \pmod n$.  We could have $a+b \equiv j\pmod n$ and $a-b\equiv k\pmod n$ and that would be true.

......

To tie this all together.

1a)  If $n = 1$ then $a \equiv 0 \pmod 1$. Always.  And $a^2 \equiv b^2\pmod 1 \implies a\equiv b \equiv 0 \pmod 1$.  But this is trivial and silly.

1b)  If $n=2$ then $a \equiv -a\pmod 2$. ($1 \equiv -1\pmod 2$ and $0\equiv 0$) and $a^2 \equiv b^2 \pmod 2 \implies a \equiv b\pmod 2$.  But this is the last case this is true.

2. If $n > 2$ then there will be some $a$ where $a \not \equiv -a \pmod n$ so $a^2 \equiv (-a)^2 \pmod n$ but $a \not \equiv -a \pmod n$ so this will never be true for $n > 2$

BUT  $a^2 \equiv b^2 \pmod n \implies a \equiv \pm b \pmod n$ if $n$ is prime.

If $n$ is prime then

$a^2 \equiv b^2 \pmod n \implies (a-b)(a+b)\equiv 0 \pmod p$.

So that means $p|(a-b)(a+b)$.  But if $p$ is prime then by Euclid's lemma we either have $p|a-b$ so $a\equiv b \pmod n$.  Or we have $p|a+b$ and $a \equiv -b\pmod n$.

If $n$ is not prime.... well it could still be true that $a^2 \equiv b^2 \implies a\equiv \pm b$.  For example $n=6$ we have $0^2,1^2, 2^2, 3^2, 4^2, 5^2\equiv 0,1,4,3,4,5$ and the result is true.

But it doesn't have to be.  If $a^2 \equiv b^2 \pmod n$ we well have $n|(a+b)(a-b)$.

If $n$ is not prime and it is possible that $d|n$ and $d|a+b$ where $\frac nd|(a-b)$ we can have a contradiction.

One issue is that $(a+b),(a-b)$ are either both even or both odd so $n = 2p$ where $p$ is prime will be impossible.  But otherwise it will be.

So .....

If $n\le 2$ then $a^2 \equiv b^2 \mod n \implies a\equiv b \pmod n$.

If $n > 2$ and $n$ is prime or $n = 2p; p$ prime then $a^2 \equiv b^2 \mod n\implies a \equiv \pm b \pmod n$.

Otherwise there are exceptions.

Comment: I didn’t notice that $n=2p \implies a\equiv \pm b \pmod n$ good answer.

Comment: Well, as a counter example I tried it for $6$ but there weren't any counter examples. And realized that if $6|(a+b)(b-c)$ then $3$ must divide one of $a+b,a-c$ and $2$ must divide *both* so $6$ must divide one of them.  That would hold for any $2p$.  But if you have $4p$ or $8$ or more then two odd prime factors you can have $n|(a+b)(a-b)$ without having $n$ divide either of the them.

Answer (score 0):

Hint:take $a \equiv -b \pmod{n}$

Answer (score 0):

If you mean restrictions solely on $n$, then the only $n$ for which this is true is $n = 1,2$.

If $n \geq 3$, then there is always an element $a$ with $a \neq -a$.

Taking $b := -a$,
$a^2 = b^2$ but $a \neq b$.

---

In general, when $n$ is not prime, there can be more that just these two elements which square to the same thing: for example in $\mathbb{Z} / 8 \mathbb{Z}$, each of $1,3,5,7$ square to $1$!

Answer (score 0):

The issue is when will $n|(a^2 - b^2) = (a-b)(a+b)$ imply that $n|(a-b)$.  An intermediate result of number theory is that $r|st$ and $r$ relatively prime to $t$ implies that $r|s$.

Applying that to your query, a **sufficient** condition is if $n$ is relatively prime to $(a+b)$.  The word *sufficient* is emphasized to indicate that *individual* examples are certainly feasible where $n$ is not relatively prime to $(a+b)$, but $n$ still divides $(a-b)$.

Answer (score 0):

We can say
$$
a^2 \equiv b^2 \mod n \implies (a - b)(a + b) \equiv 0 \mod n
$$
Bezout says $\exists s, t \in \mathbb{Z}$
$$
s(a + b) + tn = \gcd (a + b, n)
$$
Which means
$$
s(a + b) \equiv \gcd(a + b, n) \mod n
$$
So that
$$
(a - b) \gcd(a + b, n) \equiv 0\mod n
$$
And I don't know if we can say anything more than this.

Of course if $\gcd(a + b, n) \equiv 1 \mod n$, then we can say
$$
a \equiv b \mod n
$$
Otherwise, I'm not sure we can say much.